# curl: SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: linux, curl, rhel, rhel7

For installation of k9s i wanted to update curl. I used these comands (on RHEL 7.6):

```
wget https://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/curl-7.79.1-1.0.cf.fc20.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i curl-7.79.1-1.0.cf.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

And now even if i do "curl localhost" i get:

```
*   Trying 10.0.17.134:3131...
* Connected to 10.0.17.134 (10.0.17.134) port 3131 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*  CAfile: none
*  CApath: none
* loaded libnssckbi.so
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

Now i know that i shouldn't have update Curl, especially from city-fan repo, but it's too late.
What can i do for undone what i did?